# Windows 11 dev drive: how and why does it work?

Tags: performance, filesystems, windows-11, development

Windows 11 has a "dev drive" feature which can improve performance of developer workloads. Developer drives use ReFS.

Questions:

1. Why is using ReFS going to help performance? After all, in general, changing to a more advanced filesystem is usually not going improve performance.
2. Can we use it in other scenarios like gaming to improve performance?
3. Are there similar ideas before for linux and other OS?

Comment: One question per post please. What does the documentation for this feature say? Different systems may be optimized for different workloads. I would guess that gaming vs dev workloads are very different. Also, re q3: product recommendations are explicitly off topic on this site.

Comment: @music2myear They are all related questions. It is not a product recommendation question.

Comment: Relation does not mean they are the same question. You have asked WHY ReFS improves performance for dev work, whether ReFS would work for gaming, and whether there are products like this for other OSes. They are different questions, despite their relation. This is a "Question and Answer" site. The goal is that a single answer can be good and authoritative, and that then means that each post must be limited to a single question. The form follows the purpose.

Comment: A quick web search brought me here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/devdrive/ and taught me this: "With Dev Drive, you can create a separate volume on your PC that will improve performance for disk-bound operations such as cloning, building, copying files, and package restore. We measured average improvements in these operations around of 25%" It seems more efficient for small file work with lots of reading and writing from disk. Games don't do that and are instead bounded by memory, CPU, or GPU mainly.

Answer (score 5):

1. Windows Dev Drives offer improved performance for development workflows due to doing *less*, actually. The main difference is that various filesystem filters/hooks don't run on the Dev Drive, most notably putting the Windows Defender live antivirus protection in a less hyperactive (but also less secure) operation mode. Windows Defender serializing and blocking IO is the primary source of Windows-specific IO slowness. It's not (primarily) ReFS offering the improved performance, it's the other tuning done by default for Dev Drive partitions. (It does make that tuning more practical, though, AIUI.)
2. It might, but it's unlikely to. The IO performance boost is primarily in minimizing per-operation overhead, especially on file creation/writes. Games typically bundle their assets and have large chunked read patterns instead of the bursty patterns seen in development workflows.
3. Windows Dev Drive is about getting the Windows filesystem closer to the Linux filesystem performance. Linux manages its filesystem very differently from Windows, and as a result, Linux is much more performant in many-small-file developer workflows than Windows is, even when using a Dev Drive. Because Dev Drive is about tuning Windows-specific filesystem properties, the techniques used there are highly unlikely to apply to other OSes' filesystems.